# Referring filenames inside python loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 5 dataframes as below. I need to print the number of records of each file using a for loop. How can i achieve this?

```
f1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
f2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
f3=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
f4=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
f5=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
```

I tried the below code,

```
for i in range(1,6):
    j='f'+str(i)
    print(j.shape)
```

and got error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape', since the loop created strings f1,f2,f3,f4,f5. Is there any other way to refer filenames and do operations on them in loops? Also - is this a good practice?

other operations i want to do are as below for all dataframes in a loop not just in  for loop

```
df1=f1.loc[(f1.number > 0.5) & (f1.number<1)]
df2=f2.loc[(f2.number > 0.5) & (f2.number<1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list with 5 elements and loop through it.

```
f = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)).
     pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)),
     pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)),
     pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)),
     pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10)),
]

for j in f:
    print(j.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will using `locals`

```
for i in range(1,6):
    j='f'+str(i)
    print(locals()[j].shape)  

(10, 1)
(10, 1)
(10, 1)
(10, 1)
(10, 1)
```